# «Оценивается 0 баллов» или «оценивается в 0 баллов»?

Tags: грамматика, лексическая-сочетаемость

*Если сочинение менее 70 слов, то такая работа не засчитывается и оценивается 0 баллов.*

Смущает отсутствие предлога ***в*** в словосочетании "оценивается 0 баллов"
(хотя если **0** заменить, к примеру, на **5**, то смущения немного убавляется, но все-таки не до конца).

P.S. пробовал самостоятельно разобраться, но, к сожалению, ничего, кроме [словаря сочетаемости](https://rkiff.philol.msu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD_%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8.pdf) (в котором нужной информации тоже не оказалось),
найти не смог.

Comment: *...хотя если 0 заменить, к примеру, на 5, то смущения немного убавляется, но все-таки не до конца.* Ерунда!

Comment: Скорее всего, здесь имеется в виду "оценивается нулём баллов".